# Limit number of characters delimited by a comma?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex which only allows numbers delimited by  comma.

```
/^(?:\d+(?:, *|))*\d+$/
```

Example:

```
12345, 123456789, 987654  //valid
```

Is there any way to modify this regex to only allow between 3 to 5 numbers before and after the commas.

Examples:

```
12345, 54321, 918, 123, 5678   //valid

12345, 1234567, 4382929001     //invalid
```

Comment: why should `12345, 123456789, 987654` be valid and why should `12345, 1234567, 4382929001` be invalid ?

Comment: because I'm trying to explain that my existing regex is valid for any length. I was looking for the regex to be modified to only accept a number length range before and after the comma.

Comment: Read a basic regexp tutorial, including about "quantifiers". Otherwise you'll need to post dozens of questions on SO for each and very feature of regexps? You could do worse than starting at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\d{3,5}[ ,]+)*\b\d{3,5}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/oM7tW1/5)

**Update:** To block multiple commas after a number use:

```
^(?:\d{3,5}(?! *, *,)[ ,]+)*\b\d{3,5}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/oM7tW1/5)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```
^\d{3,5}(?:,\s\d{3,5})*$
```

but then again I should say that you call `12345, 123456789, 987654` valid which kinda seems to me as a mistake from your part

this will allow only 3 - 5 digits in all the numbers before and after commas.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/nX8kW4/1